# Copy a batch of files from Android to PC

Tags: android, bash, adb

I wrote a piece of script to copy some files to my PC from an Android device:

```
adb shell ls /sdcard/Download/0*.log > tmp 
while read line
do  
    echo $line
    adb pull $line .
done < tmp 
rm tmp
```

However, it seems there is something I missed; it does not work. Could you help me point it out?

I got:

```
/sdcard/Download/0810-192141.log
' does not existsdcard/Download/0810-192141.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error is the extra `\r` character on the end of the `$line`. This should work:

```
adb shell "ls /sdcard/Download/0*.log" | tr -d '\r' > tmp 
while read line
do  
    echo $line
    adb pull $line .
done < tmp 
rm tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

```
adb shell ls /sdcard/Download/0\*.log > tmp
```

will work as you expect. Note the `\` to avoid the glob being interpreted by your shell.