# "adb pull" throws "does not exist"

Tags: android, adb

When I perform command:

`for el in $(adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/ | grep mem_); do adb pull /mnt/sdcard/${el} android_mem; done`

I get:

`' does not existmnt/sdcard/mem_AI
' does not existmnt/sdcard/mem_Alarms
' does not existmnt/sdcard/mem_Android
' does not existmnt/sdcard/mem_Autodesk
' does not existmnt/sdcard/mem_Cardboard
' does not existmnt/sdcard/mem_DCIM
...`
But if I perform this, for example, `adb pull /mnt/sdcard/mem_DCIM android_mem` I get that `0 KB/s (20 bytes in 0.080s)`, ie ok. Why is this happens??

Comment: I would go `ls /mnt/sdcard/mem_*` instead

Comment: possible duplicate of [Copy a batch of files from Android to PC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167479/copy-a-batch-of-files-from-android-to-pc)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/ | grep mem_` is returning a `\r` at the end, so it can't pull the file properly.

So you need to remove it with `sed -r 's/[\r]+//g'`, for example:

```
for el in $(adb shell ls /mnt/sdcard/ | grep mem_ | sed -r 's/[\r]+//g'); do adb pull /mnt/sdcard/${el} android_mem; done
```