# shell script to get file from android sdcard with adb shell

Tags: android, shell, adb

```
#!/bin/bash
DIR_PATH="/sdcard/log/xxxxdir"

function useAdbReadLastFileFromDir(){
    fileName=`adb shell ls $1|tail -1`
    if [ -n $fileName ]
    then
        echo "fileName:"
        echo "adb pull $PATH/$fileName"
        fileContent=`adb pull $PATH/$fileName`
        echo "fileContent:"$fileContent
    else
        echo "file not found exception"
    fi
}

useAdbReadLastFileFromDir $DIR_PATH
```

---

android6.0 yotaphone/sunsang note5 can't pull file from sdcard, error message said:

```
file or dir not exist
```

but androi8.0 oppo findx/mi mix2 does.

help~!

Comment: am i wrote wrong sdcard path？？

Comment: copy the printed fileName replace var. it worked. but use the variable doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`adb pull` takes 2 mandatory parameters: `REMOTE_FILENAME` and `LOCAL_FILENAME`

If you want to `adb pull` a text file to `stdout` - use `adb shell cat FILENAME` instead

Comment: thank a lot , yeah got it, cat is also cant find file. error message is no such file or dir

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18167479/copy-a-batch-of-files-from-android-to-pc    thank for your help.